# Selenium WebDriver - Explicit wait before every test step

Tags: selenium, cucumber

I have a tendency to prevent the situations when elements I'm about to perform an action on are not visible nor clickable.

The result is I use many explicit waits, practically before every test step. Please see an example provided below.

```
@When("^User goes into Best Sellers in Digital Cameras$")
public void userGoesIntoBestSellersInDigitalCameras() {
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(mainPage.getDepartmentsButton()));
    mainPage.clickDepartmentsButton();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(departments.getCameraPhotoVideoLink()));
    departments.clickCameraPhotoVideoLink();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(cameraPhotoVideo.getBestSellersLink()));
    cameraPhotoVideo.clickBestSellersLink();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(bestSellersBestCameraPhoto.getDigitalCamerasLink()));
    bestSellersBestCameraPhoto.clickDigitalCamerasLink();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleIs(bestSellersBestDigitalCameras.getExpectedBestSellersBestDigitalCamerasPageTitle()));
}
```

Could you please advise if it is a good practice or the number of explicit waits should not be that large? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **TL;DR:** Each page object can have encapsulated its own logic in order to click a given element (and waiting for a given element before doing the actual click).

I see you have already separated your page objects using page object pattern (model), you just need to go one step further and instead of having each click method in the page object just "click" have it call a helper method which first checks to see if the element is visible, enabled, and clickable.  This way you only need to write one method that handles this and you can fine-tune it to be very well designed to handle various situations, and the page object merely needs to pass the web element as a parameter.

If you code all your page object methods this way, you never need to worry about it in the test case code at all, you know the method will always wait for the item to be clickable, and it greatly simplifies both the test case (steps) code and the page object code.

Comment: Could you please take a look at the provided code and let me know if I understood you properly? [Link to the code](https://gist.github.com/itsLukaszK/291dd60867cd3968e577bdeb226ae163)

Comment: Yes, that is the gist of what I was saying.

Comment: Thanks! I have one more question: Should I create the 'isClickable' and 'clickElement' methods in every page class? Is there maybe some way to handle that 'globally' and still not be in conflict with Page Object Pattern (Model) rules?

Comment: Yes.  In fact, I have a separate helper file where all the methods start with 'pom', i.e. pomExists, pomClick, pomSendKeys, pomGetText, etc. and include that package in page object base class so that the Selenium functions are all wrapped with try/catch, wait, etc. so my page objects might have method userIDClick that calls pomClick(userID) which does the wait, and other common logic I want done anytime I click any element.